# How to build a pseudo number generator to have same result in JS and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, random-seed, generate

After I build a JS function that generates pseudo numbers from initial seed I created the same function in C# expecting to get the same results. After 6 iterations the results where different... Can someone help me to build such a function that generates same values in JS and also in C# ?

```
using System;

public class PSR
{
    public int ITN { get; private set; } = 0;
    public int IntITN { get; private set; } = 0;

    private double seed;

    public PSR(double seed)
    {
        this.seed = seed + 0.5;  // avoid 0
    }

    public double Next()
    {
        ITN++;
        var x = Math.Sin(this.seed) * 1000;
        var result = x - Math.Floor(x);  // [0.0,1.0)
        this.seed = result;  // for next call
        return result;
    }

    public double NextInt(double lo, double hi)
    {
        IntITN++;
        var x = this.Next();
        return Math.Truncate((hi - lo) * x + lo);
    }

}
```

TS version

```
export class Psr
{
  itn: number = 0;
  intItn:number = 0;
  constructor(private seed) {
    this.seed = seed + 0.5;  // avoid 0
  }

  next() {
    this.itn++
    let x = Math.sin(this.seed) * 1000;
    let result = x - Math.floor(x);  // [0.0,1.0)
    this.seed = result;  // for next call
    return result;
  }

  nextInt(lo, hi) {
    this.intItn++
    let x = this.next();
    return Math.trunc((hi - lo) * x + lo);
  }
}
```

Comment: javascript and c# may have different implementations of the trigonometry functions you're using.

Comment: _"After 6 iterations the results where different"_ how different were they? Just a little rounding error or completely different league?

Comment: What is the requirement which forces you to do it? Or is it just curiosity?

Comment: @Fildor just tested it. First iteration has an error at the 15th decimal place. At the 8th iteration the errors accumulated up to the first decimal place. It is unusable.

Comment: So, I would guess it's a difference in implementation that affects accuracy and the error is adding up... not much that can be done to synchronize, I think. Time for Plan B.

Comment: Is RFC-6238 TOTP an option?  You would have to use the same time step in both, and the same secret key, but they would generate the same number for both implementations.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238  This is the standard for two-factor auth pass codes used by apps like Google Authenticator.

Comment: @Josh dose it work for JS also ?

Comment: It should.  The only caveat is that you have to have the same secret and moving factor across both systems (Used by the underlying RFC-4226 implementation).  For RFC-6238, that moving factor is time steps since epoch, and by default the time step length is 30 seconds.  So, codes generated with the same secret, in the same time step, would be the same across all systems as long as you follow the algorithm.

Comment: The other downside is that if you are generating keys in rapid succession, they would generate the same code for that entire timestep.  If you have a counter that can be syncronized across both systems, you could just use RFC-4226 and have the moving factor be a counter you control.

Comment: I would go to wikipadia or Knuth to find a common alg and nice seed numbers. Trigonometry seems a bad idea for cross-library compatability. - Do note that many libs do not event guarantee stable results between versions!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an environment with C# to test with, but something like a simple [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) should works in both.

In JavaScript you might have an implementation like:

```
const random  = (seed = 3) => () => (seed = (seed * 1103515245 + 12345) % 0xffffffff) / 0xfffffff

const prng = random(); // 3 as default seed

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i ++)
  console.log(prng());
```

That shouldn't give much issues in any languages to be implemented.

Comment: In my code I replaced Next to returm:         return (seed = (seed * 1103515245 + 12345) % 0xffffffff) / 0xfffffff; in C# the values are similar but not the same I think the error will propagate